# Using SetFilePointerEx to read the last cluster of a file

Tags: c++, winapi

Need some help with the logic and clarification on what ReadFile is displaying. So the point of my little project is to find the last cluster of any file and read off the binary of the last cluster. 
As of now I am using the code below to find the last cluster address after I CreateFile() and DeviceIoControl() with control code FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS:

```
    DWORD lastExtentN = retrievalBuffer->ExtentCount - 1;
    LONGLONG lastExtent = retrievalBuffer->Extents[lastExtentN].Lcn.QuadPart;
    LONGLONG lengthOfExtent = retrievalBuffer->Extents[lastExtentN].NextVcn.QuadPart - retrievalBuffer->Extents[lastExtentN - 1].NextVcn.QuadPart;

    while (error == ERROR_MORE_DATA){

        error = GetLastError();

        switch (error){

        case ERROR_HANDLE_EOF:
            //file sizes 0-1kb will return EOF error 
            cout << "ERROR_HANDLE_EOF" << endl;
            returns = true;
            break;

        case ERROR_MORE_DATA:
            cout << "ERROR_MORE_DATA" << endl;
            startVcn.StartingVcn = retrievalBuffer->Extents[0].NextVcn;

        case NO_ERROR:
            cout << "NO_ERROR, here is some info: " << endl;
            cout << "This is the lcnextent : " << retrievalBuffer->Extents[lastExtentN].Lcn.QuadPart << endl;
            cout << "This is the nextvnc: " << retrievalBuffer->Extents[lastExtentN].NextVcn.QuadPart << endl;
            cout << "This is the Extent count: " << retrievalBuffer->ExtentCount << endl;
            cout << "This is the Starting Vnc: " << retrievalBuffer->StartingVcn.QuadPart << endl;
            cout << "The length of the cluster is: " << lengthOfExtent << endl;
            cout << "The last cluster is: " << lastExtent + lengthOfExtent - 1 << endl << endl << endl;

            returns = true;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Error in the code or input error" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Next I use GetDiskFreeSpace() to find out cluster info:

```
diskClust = GetDiskFreeSpace(pathFile,
                                 &dwSectPerClust,
                                 &dwBytesPerSect,
                                 &dwFreeClusters,
                                 &dwTotalClusters);
```

After I find out the cluster size:

```
// Get cluster size
    DWORD totalClusterSize = dwSectPerClust * dwBytesPerSect;
    cout << "Sectors Per Cluster " << dwSectPerClust << " * Bytes Per Sector " << dwBytesPerSect << " = Cluster size: " << totalClusterSize << endl;
```

Next I use CreateFile() to set a handle to the disk volume followed by `SetFilePointerEx()`:

```
LARGE_INTEGER dist;
    dist.QuadPart = (lastExtent + lengthOfExtent - 1) * totalClusterSize;
    BOOL res = SetFilePointerEx(hDevice, dist, nullptr, FILE_BEGIN);
    if (!res){
        // handle error
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        cout<<GetLastError()<<GetLastError()<<endl;
        if (error == ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE){
            cout << "ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE" << endl;
        }
        cout << "'There is an error with SetFilePointerEX" << endl;
    }
```

Finally I use ReadFile() in the attempt to read the last cluster of the file:

```
DWORD nRead;

    unsigned int buff[4096];

    BOOL fileFromVol = ReadFile(hDevice,
                                buff,
                                4096,
                                &nRead,
                                NULL);

    if (fileFromVol == 0){         //Error handling
        cout << "Error with fileFromVol" << "\n\n";
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
            if (error == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED){
                cout << "error_access_denied"<<endl;
            }
        cout << GetLastErrorStdStr() << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    cout<<"\n\n"<<buff<<"\n\n";
```

Sorry this post is so lengthy but I used a lot of code snippets to reference. So my confusions are:

- Does this look like the last cluster of a file: `lastExtent +
  lengthOfExtent - 1`   Does 4096 bytes seem right for cluster size:
  `DWORD totalClusterSize = dwSectPerClust * dwBytesPerSect;`
- Would it make sense to take the last cluster * the cluster size in
  order to move the file pointer to the last cluster:`dist.QuadPart =
  (lastExtent + lengthOfExtent - 1) * totalClusterSize;`

Finally, I'm reading the data into a buffer and printing it: `cout<<"\n\n"<<buff<<"\n\n";`
So I tested this on a text file with a bunch of 'a's and it gave me a hexadecimal result of 010F3290 which I believe is translated in string to a 2 which doesn't really make sense. Feel free to criticize any of the code, ask any questions about it, or make any suggestions. Any help would be great.

Comment: I am not exactly sure why my post got downvoted so much. Is because of how I formated the question? Please let me know so I can improve my questions for future posts. Yes I read through "How to ask a question" and "How to Ask."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that the first cluster (LCN 0) starts at the first sector of the volume.  This is wrong.

You can use [`FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTER_BASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the sector offset from the start of the volume to the first LCN.

By my figuring, the correct formula for the byte offset of the final cluster is

```
dist.QuadPart = (FileAreaOffset * dwBytesPerSect) + 
                ((lastExtent + lengthOfExtent - 1) * totalClusterSize);
```

Comment: This seems like it's working. Now I have an issue were my dist.QuadPart is constant but my ReadFile() function gives me a different hexadecimal address every time I run the program. Any ideas why?